# ApplicationSettingsBindings get lost after reopening the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, user-controls, designer

I'm using ApplicationSettings to store strings which appear often in my Forms. I created something like a "multiline-label" named TextView as a UserControl, applying the Text through the following code... If I reopen or "Rebuild Solution", the text-binding is removed, but other property bindings still exist.

```
   [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
   //for showing the property in the code Designer
    [SettingsBindable(true)]
    //allows to create an ApplicationSettings Binding in the Designer
    public override string Text
    {
        get{  return text;}
        set{ text = value; draw(); }
    }
```

ApplicationSettings Bindings how I would like to keep them
[PdbDr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdbDr.png)
ApplicationSettings Bindings after reopening my project
[fMySp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMySp.png)

(I'm sorry, I can't post images yet)

I've already tried using "new" instead of "override", like I'm doing it for BackColor, Font . But nothing changed.
If it could help, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Comment: You are fighting the attributes on UserControl.Text, I think you'll solve your problem when you add [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem , made my day, I'd like to mark your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]` ~ thanks to Hans Passant